# Типизация new Set() в typeScript

Tags: typescript, коллекции, типизация

[image: Добрый вечер. Пытаюсь создать newSet на TS но компилятор выдает вот такую ошибку. Совсем не понимаю как это сделать правильно.]

```
const uniqueArray = new Set(Array)
```

Добрый вечер. Пытаюсь создать newSet на TS но компилятор выдает вот такую ошибку. Совсем не понимаю как это сделать правильно.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на «StackOverflow на русском»! [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12119/#12120).

Comment: А с чего вы решили что Set это массив? Может всё-таки `x: Set<string> = new Set(cityCatalog)`?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Об этом даже в ошибке сказано )

Comment: Ну и если у `cityCatalog` определён нормальный тип, то TS [сам выведет](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEEQBd5gJbIJ4GErKggHsBzALngGdkZ0A7EgbQF0BuAKHaVQA94BeeHRAB3eAGUUACgzY8BYiQCUHAPSr48AHoB+IA) нужный тип.

Comment: Да) разобрался. Спасибо. Только начинаю в нем разбираться и пока все идет туго

Answer (score 0):

```
const x = new Set<string>(cityCatalog);
const y: string[] = [...x];
```

Таким образом получилось создать уникальный массив нужного типа